# Understanding array pointer initialization syntax in C

Tags: c, arrays

I come from a Java background and in C I am little bit confused about the C array syntax.

When I initialize an array in C I do this:

```
int arr[5];
```

As far as I understand it correctly this actually gives a pointer to arr that points to the first element of the array on the stack.

But then I don't understand why the array initialization does not look like this since we receive a pointer:

```
int* arr[5];
```

This gives me something I don't  understand. Maybe an array of 5 pointers?

On the other hand this is totally valid again:

```
int arr[5];
int* p = arr;
```

So why is it done like this? Shouldn't the initalization syntax be with an int* instead of an int since we actually receive a pointer?

Comment: `int arr[5];` ... array of 5 `int`. `int *arr[5];` ... array of 5 `int*`. `int (*arr)[5];` ... pointer to array of 5 `int`. Yeah, that's tricky. (IMHO, this is the most hard part when learning C.) This may help: [C to gibberish](https://cdecl.org/?q=int*%20arr[5]).

Comment: "why" ... C is quite old language, with idea to be capable to write assembler class solutions in more portable way. 2 it is lightweight, no array bounds checking (like few years younger Pascal) etc

Comment: The first is an array of 5 integers. An array is not a pointer, although it may decay to a pointer to the first element. The second is an array of 5 pointers. In the third, `int* p = arr;` is assigning a pointer (which the array decays to) to a pointer variable. I suggest you place the `*` with the variable name, not with its type, such as `int *p;`. If you define, for example, `int* p, q;` you have not defined two pointer variables, but one pointer and one integer. This would be clearer as `int *p, q;`

Comment: You do not "actually receive a pointer", you receive an array. `int[5]` means an object whose layout is 5 contiguous `int`s. The line `int arr[5];` makes one of those objects called `arr`.  It is analogous to `int y;` except the object is 5 times as big and you can refer to its sub-objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C syntax this line declares an array of 5 pointers to `int`.

```
int* arr[5];
```

Below an array of 5 `int`s is declared.

```
int arr[5];
```

The line above told the compiler to reserve in memory 5 times the size of `int` in adjacent addresses of memory starting at `&arr[0]`. While `arr` is not a pointer, itself, if used as a name, `arr`, decays to a pointer to the first slot (so `arr` is equivalent to `&a[0]`).

```
int* p = arr;
```

`p` is an ordinary pointer to `int`, assigned to a valid memory address, the same as `arr` (or `&arr[0]` )

Arrays and pointers differ. The first difference is 'arr' is a constant and can't be reassigned to other addresses.

**For example the following is invalid**

```
arr++;
```

While the following is **valid**

```
p++;
```

Furthermore pointers require extra dereference underlying ASM operations, whereas arrays don't

```
char arr[7];
char *p = arr;
```

---

**Arrays indexing**

Compare this line and its ASM instructions:

```
char a = arr[7];
```

0041137E  mov  al,byte ptr [_array_place+7 (417007h)]

00411383  mov  byte ptr [a],al

---

**Pointer indexing:**

With this line and its ASM instructions:

```
char b = p[7];
```

00412DD7  mov  eax,dword ptr [ptr_arg]

00412DDA  mov  cl,byte ptr [eax+7]

00412DDD  mov  byte ptr [b],cl

---

Arrays can **decay** to pointers to the first element. This happens frequently, e.g. when you pass them as function arguments. In that case, treat them as pointers inside the called function. You can eventually label them as [constant pointers or pointers to constant or constant pointers to constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const).

I hope this clarifies.